# Notify Users when Child is added on specific node using Cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible for cloud function to listen for specific node for when a child is added and then send a notification to users located on a different node, and if that is possible how so? I am using node.js with Firebase realtime database and not Firestore.

This is my database:
[image: Database Structure]

I want the cloud function to listen every time a child is added on "Emergencies", and then notify all the users in the "Registered Admins"

This is the contents of the users in "Registered Admins" node, it has a child "Notification"  containing the message, and I want to send that message to all the users, when a child is added on "Emergencies" node.

[image: A user in w/notification message in "Registered Admins"]

[image: Token ID of the user in "Registered Admins"]

This is my cloud function using node.js. I've deployed it however it does not work, does not send any notification at all.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.listen = functions.database.ref("/Emergencies")
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {
  change.after.val();
  context.params.pushId;

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
      .ref("/Registered Admins/{uid}/Token").once("value");

  // The snapshot to the user's tokens.
  let tokensSnapshot;

  // The array containing all the user's tokens.
  let tokens;

  const results = await Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]);
  tokensSnapshot = results[0];
  
  // Check if there are any device tokens.
  if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
    return functions.logger.log(
      'There are no notification tokens to send to.'
    );
  }
  functions.logger.log(
    'There are',
    tokensSnapshot.numChildren(),
    'tokens to send notifications to.'
  );

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {
  notification: {
      title: "New Emergency Request!",
      body: "Someone needs help check Emergenie App now!",
    }
  }; 

  // Listing all tokens as an array.
  tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
  // Send notifications to all tokens.
  const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  // For each message check if there was an error.
  const tokensToRemove = [];
  response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      functions.logger.error(
        'Failure sending notification to',
        tokens[index],
        error
      );
      // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
        tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
      }
    }
  });
  return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
});
```

Comment: Yes, that sounds possible and is in fact quite close to what the example on [notifying users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) does. If you're having a hard time making that work for your data, I recommend showing us what you tried based on that example and your data, and showing [where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do the users in "Registered Admins" requires a device tokenID to receive a notification? is there a way to do that without requiring device token ID, since I will be sending the notification message to all the accounts in "Required Admins"

Comment: To send a message to a specific device, you 'll need to know the token for that device. If you want to broadcast a message to multiple users, you could subscribe those users to a topic. Just keep in mind that anyone can subscribe to a topic if they know its name, so you can't use that to send messages that only a certain group of users is allowed to see.

Comment: What do you mean by "anyone can subscribe to a topic if they know its name?" you mean anyone using my app? or literally anyone? if so, I would just need to make a unique name for the topic?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my post with my cloud function

Comment: Hey Timow. Good to see that you got started with the Cloud Function that I linked. Note that asking us for help in debugging that Cloud Function is a new question, so I recommend opening a new post for this. In there you should also include the debugging you've already done, as Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. For example: if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how to debug my node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that sounds possible and is in fact quite close to what the example on [notifying users when something interesting happens does](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

To send a message to a specific device, you 'll need to know the token for that device. If you want to broadcast a message to multiple users, you could subscribe those users to a topic. Just keep in mind that anyone can subscribe to a topic if they know its name, so you can't use that to send messages that only a certain group of users is allowed to see.

Comment: I've read the example on that link, and it seems like its trying to notify a single user only. however in my case I want to notify a group of users(all of the users in "Registered Admin") and those users are using a different application, than the one who sent the emergency request

Comment: Is there a way to get all the tokenID of all the users in "Registered Admins" and send them a notification using FCM?

Comment: FCM has no knowledge of your users, so the only way to build such a list of tokens for them is by capturing the tokens yourself and storing them yourself. Then when you want to notify all registered admins, you can read their tokens - similar to what the example I linked does.

Comment: Okay thank you I will check on that. Does the link you sent also includes FCM notification on the cloud function? 

Also how do I get multiple tokens? from multiple user accounts?