# Loop that gets all the tokens from the all the users inside a node in firebase realtime database?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So I am new to javascript and cloud function, and I have this code to send notification on a device when a data is created on a particular node. This code works and it was able to send notification whenever data is added, however it only sends on a specific device since I only did use a single token for testing. What I want to know, is how do I get every all the tokens from each user located on a specific node. I understand that I have to use a loop and put the tokens in an array, but how should I do that? Are there any sample code that I could work with. Thank you any help would be appreciated.

This is my database structure:

```
Database name
{
"Registered Admins": {
"0zPSXiHR05PG2MogS0l4xzWuMUc2": {
  "User Details",
  "User Details",
  "Token": "etms39B4TzCYBujRNhcAQE.........",
  "User Details"
},
"bwjOH8ndKeeMfwy5UvhChVtyNov1": {
  "User Details"
  "Token": "etms39B4TzCYBujRNhcAQE........."
  "User Details"
     }
}
}
```

This is my javascript code:

```
"use strict";

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotificationtoDevice = 
functions.database.ref("/Emergencies/{pushId}")
.onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
// Load all the users from Registered Admins
  const adminsSnapshot = await admin.database().ref("/Registered 
Admins").once("value");
let tokens = [];
// Loop over adminsSnapshot
adminsSnapshot.forEach((adminSnapshot) => {
tokens.push(adminSnapshot.child("Token").val());
});
console.log(tokens);
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "New Emergency!",
    body: "Someone needs help check application now!",
  },
};
console.log("Hello User");
await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
});
```

This is what I've tried with Firebase emulator suite:
I tried recreating the same structure by importing json file, and also checked for database triggers.
[image: Checkbox for executing triggers]
[image: Realtime Database]

I also tried recreating the same scenario in which I added data on "Emergencies" node. However it still doesnt logs the tokens or even "Hello User"
[image: Functions Logs]

How should I debug using the emulators suite? I cant seem to find any docs that could help me in this

Comment: Didn't we already cover this in your previous question(s) about the topic? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652232/notify-users-when-child-is-added-on-specific-node-using-cloud-function If you can't get the code there to work, debug the problem and include that debug information in your question.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen Do you have a sample code that can do this? 
    


1. Load all of /Registered Admins
2. Loop over the results you get from that
3. Get the Token value for each of them

Comment: The example in the documentation that I linked in my answer to that question does precisely that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens. If you're having a hard time applying that to your data structure, debug the problem. As I said before, this'll be much easier if you do it in a local process, the Firebase emulators, or a web page than in live Cloud Function. Check where your code differs from the working example. Can you explain what each difference does?

Comment: E.g. `admin.database().ref("/Registered Admins/{uid}/Token").once("value");` that `{uid}` in there won't work as loading from the database doesn't interpret it. You'll want to load all of `/Registered Admins` and then loop over the snapshot that you get back, getting the `Token` property of each.

Comment: I have tried firebase emulator suite, but somehow the logs in firebase functions does not show anything when I added something on the database emulator

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do I load all the /Registered Admins?

Comment: `admin.database().ref("/Registered Admins).once("value")`. But we're now back to your previous code and how to debug that. I strongly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as this has very little to do with how to send a push notification from Cloud Functions, and everything with a much smaller problem: how to load and loop over data that you load from Firebase. Isolating the problem makes it much more likely someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do I loop over the snapshots after loading the users?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my javascript code it still wont get the tokens

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the code is working now! Thank you for your help and understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load all tokens from `/Registered Admins`, you can do:

```
const adminsSnapshot = await admin.database().ref("/Registered Admins").once("value");
let tokens = [];
adminsSnapshot.forEach((adminSnapshot) => {
  tokens.push(adminSnapshot.child("Token").val());
});
console.log(tokens);
```

You can use those tokens to call the FCM API to send a message to all of them.

Comment: I've changed the javascript code, but it still doest send any notifications

Comment: I tried using the firebase emulators, specifically realtime database emulator and functions emulator. however when I tried simulating what I'm doing online, it doesnt write logs, even when I write console.log() methods.

Comment: Please please please learn to [**isolate your problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I very intentionally only do `console.log(tokens)` with the tokens from the database in my answer, so that you can check if that part works. If the log shows the tokens, the code in my answer worked and any remaining problems for the use-case are elsewhere. If the code in my answer doesn't log the tokens, we can continue to figure out why that is. But by continuing to focus only on the use-case, you're making it harder to help as we're constantly getting back to "it doesn't send any notifications".

Comment: I understand that by using console.log(tokens) I can check if the tokens are successfully fetched from the database. I've tried the same thing in firebase emulator suite, as shown in my edit, but logs wont write in function logs section of the emulator. I dont understand why it wont show. I am now trying to debug it locally like you said earlier.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear

Comment: The problem is not in not being clear, your use-case is quite clear by now. The problem is that you're posting question about the use-case rather than an isolated problem. This makes it hard for us to post a concise answer, as shown in this post. I answered "How to load the tokens from <your data structure> in Node.js" (which isolates it from FCM and even Cloud Functions, but your response was first "it still doest send any notifications" and now "I can't get my functions to work in the emulator suite".

Comment: To isolate: start from scratch, create a Node.js script, load the Admin SDK in there, initialize it, connect to RTDB and read a single value. If any of those fails, **that** is you problem and not yet loading tokens. Once all of these previous steps work, try loading the tokens with the code from my answer. If everything before works yet loading the tokens doesn't work, this question is a good place to follow up. Once this also works, try calling FCM with the tokens to send a notification. Step by step, isolating each problem to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay I get it now! I have to check if I can successfully read from RTDB first. Thanks I'll try that!

Comment: Hi the code works now!  I was able to get the following tokens from the users and succesfully send it to the devices using FCM using the code you provided earlier.  Thank you for your effort at helping me, I apologize again for not following the proper way of asking questions. I am learning a lot from here! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Timow. 